# Quartile groups excel

Tags: statistics

I have a list of 74 numbers that I would like to place in equal groups determined by their quartiles.
I.e. 4 groups. to my current understanding this is not possible, because 74 is not divisible by 4. Am I correct in my thinking or is there an other way?

I am using excel

Comment: I don't understand what you want us to say. Indeed you cannot make four groups with equal amount of elements, with a total of 74 elements. That you understood yourself. So what should we do?

Answer (score 1):

The *median* of a set of values is the middle occurring value.  In the case that there is an even number of values, the median is the arithmetic mean of the two middling values.

The first quartile is the median of the lower half of the set of values, and the third quartile is the median of the upper half of the set of values.  Use the above definition of *median* to determine the quartiles.

The second quartile is, naturally, just the median.

**Example 1:**  the set $$\{1,5,11,12,45\}$$ has $3$, $11$, and $28.5$ for Q1, Q2, and Q3.

**Example 2:**  the set $$\{1,5,12,45\}$$ has $3$, $8.5$, and $28.5$ for Q1, Q2, and Q3.